# Graph Traversal: Upper and Lower Bounds

Tags: search-trees

In my Artificial Intelligence class we are going over upper and lower bounds in regards to searching a tree, given a state space.

From my understanding, a lower bound is also known as a depth-bound and sets a limit on how far down a tree we can search.

But if that's a lower bound, then what would an upper bound be? We're not searching up the tree.

Comment: I don't know what terminology you use in your AI class, but a limit on how far down you have to search actually corresponds to a time *upper* bound.

Comment: We've covered what a depth-bound is, and I understand what that means. Is there such a thing as an upper bound on a graph-search?

Comment: An upper bound on an algorithm usually means an upper bound on the running time of the algorithm. In your case, if the search should only look so far down, then the running time is only so much, so you get an upper bound on the running time.

Comment: *Lower* and *upper* don't refer to the tree. Rather, they have the same meaning as the calculus terms "greatest lower bound" and "smallest upper bound", appearing in the definition of $\inf$ and $\sup$.